# controlling joopz, probably jquery or php

Tags: c#, java, php, jquery, json

there's a site:
http://joopz.com

you can use a browser to send a receive text messages

do you think it is possible for me to programmatically control and gather data from the browser? this would mean i can make a database of incoming text messages to the browser and i could also programmatically send text messages from the browser>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I skim read their terms and FAQ and nothing appears to be written in there about it.

It is very possible to grab web pages and do authentication with PHP. Its not simple but very possible.

To send an SMS you would send a HTTP request to the server with the correct post variables.

http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/

To read from the website you would use

```
$var = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com");
```